# Column "PLANT_ID" not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two classes and i tried to make an association between them, but when i try to run this query on them

```
insert into purchase_order (id, plant_id, start_date, end_date, cost)
    values (1, 2, '2016-03-22', '2016-03-24', 600);
```

I face with following error

```
 Column "PLANT_ID" not found in sql statement
```

here is the **PurchaseOrder** class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PurchaseOrder {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      @OneToOne
      PlantInventoryEntry plant_id;

      LocalDate issueDate;
      LocalDate paymentSchedule;
      @Column(precision=8,scale=2)
      BigDecimal cost;

      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      POStatus status;
      LocalDate startDate;
      LocalDate endDate;
    }
```

here is its **jpa** interface:

```
@Repository
public interface PlantRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, Long>{

}
```

and here is **PlantInventoryEntry**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PlantInventoryEntry {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      @OneToOne
      PurchaseOrder plant_id;

      String name;
      String description;

      String price;

}
```

and its `jpa`

```
 @Repository
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository  extends JpaRepository<PlantInventoryEntry, Long>{

}
```

as you can see i have the plant_id in my purchase_order table,
but why it doesn't work?

Comment: That means the table in the database does not have a column named `PLANT_ID`.  It has nothing to do with your Java code.

Comment: but in spring-mvc i create my tables using my java code. right?

Comment: You might have created the table using a prior version that did not have `PLANT_ID`? Look in the database to see what the table looks like. If necessary drop the table and recreate it.

Comment: Although the database has column `PLANT_ID`, there's no (proper) mapping for JPA. It should be something like:  `@OneToOne(mappedBy="plantId") PlantInventoryEntry plantInventoryEntry;`

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.

The table `purchase_order` has not the column `PLANT_ID`.

Sometimes the problem could be also related to the capitalization, it depends from the configuration of your database, so if the column plant_id exists check also if has the same capitalization.

This problem is not related to the JPA, you can have it also trying directly the query in a standard client database.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the database. The only thing i have is **.sql**
which keeps my query and its only for testing. it is located **src/test/java**